# Wifi stops working in 13.10

Tags: wireless, 13.10

OK, my wifi is connecting fine, but it just stop downloading and uploading data.
The skype stops, trying to reconnect, the firefox nighly and the google chromium stops loading pages and websites, everythings stops.
But when I see the network icon: connected to my wifi.

Then, I simply reconnect, or disconnect and connect again.
Reconnecting, the wifi starts working again, the skype icon turns green, the browsers work again.

Previously, I had 13.04 and never had this problem. When I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10, the wifi started to do this. And the wifi has this problem since the early times of 13.10; since I installed 13.10, the wifi is having this issue (from the first day I installed it).

Anyone having the same problem? Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: I might be having the same problem on 12.04.  Do you notice a pattern where once you "connect" to your AP, your internet connection works for a short time then (while still connected to the AP) can't access internet hosts?  Also, what's the output of typing `arp -an` in a terminal?

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the contents of the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.  No internet then go to this link for running the script without internet.
[url]http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12350385[/url]

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that connections keep up and running, but can't connect or load any site, host, vps, server, anything that needs internet. The connection is on, but not working.
I then disconnect and connect and it works again. WEIRD...

Comment: It was fixed already a long time ago. But thanks for all your answers.

Answer (score 2):

I could not even connect to my building's wifi but for some reason I was able to connect to a friend's wifi network somewhere else. I tried many of the suggestions in here after researching for hours. In the end what did was reverting back to the previous Linux kernel installed, 3.8.x. 13.10 install with the newer kernel version 3.11 and that seems to be the root of a lot of issues.